# How to blank all cases with a specific year in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have 3 datasets each from a particular year. I have already merge all 3 but I want to blank cases where year=2016. So far this is the syntax I came up with:

```
Do (if subyr=2016).
  Recode X1 to X32 (Lowest to Highest=SYMIS)(Else=SYMIS).
  End if.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use

```
DO IF (subyr=2016) .
RECODE X1 TO X32 (ELSE=SYSMIS) .
END IF .
EXE .
```

If you ever wanted to code the valid values differently from the SYSMIS values, you could use

```
DO IF (subyr=2016) .
RECODE X1 TO X32 (LO THRU HI=0)(ELSE=SYSMIS) .
END IF .
EXE .
```

which would give you that flexibility. This example sets valid values to 0 and keep SYSMIS values as SYSMIS.